# Can Denoising Diffusions only learn white noise, and/or no drift?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-models, diffusion

I understand that it works best for image generation to add white noise and no drift because is simpler.

My question is, theoretically speaking, can the noise follow a certain distribution and the drift can be any function of state and time (signal), and the neural networks can learn to distinguish it from noise?

A lot of diffusion papers do not get into this discussion but I have a tendency to slim though